# Kolmogorov-smirnov two-sample confidence level

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I do not find information about how to calculate the $c(\alpha)$ "by hand" (see wikipedia article for two samples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) for the formula:
 $ D_{n,m} > c(\alpha)\sqrt{\frac{n+m}{nm}} $

I would like to try different levels of $\alpha$ not included in the table provided in the article.

Comment: See [Marsaglia et al. (2003) "Evaluating Kolmogorov's Distribution", *Journal of Statistical Software*, **8**, 18](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i18/) for calculation of the distribution of the test statistic in small samples.

Comment: The point is that my sample sizes are really big (close to 70,000 observations each one).

Comment: So use the asymptotic distribution.

Comment: Note that in the linked answer $K=\sqrt{\frac{nm}{n+m}}D_{n,m}$.